# Block Gauss -Seidel Iterative Method for Overdetermined Linear Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am interested in solving a large linear system with block Gauss-Seidel Iterative Method. Suppose I have the following block matrix $A$ for $Ax=b$ linear system:

\begin{bmatrix} B & 0 & C & 0 \\ 0 & C & D & 0 \\ D & 0 & D & E \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & F \end{bmatrix}

where each block matrix is $n \times n$. Right hand side vector ,$b$ , is a zero vector. So far everything is fine because $A$ matrix is a square. However I have one more equation:

$\sum{x e} = 1$

where $e$ is a vector of ones. According to my best knowledge I can use Gauss-Seidel method if $A$ is a square matrix. In my case, the linear system is overdetermined, thus not square. My question is:

Can I use Gauss-Seidel method for this problem with some pre-work?
If not, what do you recommend me to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can calculate the [least squares solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#The_general_problem), that is, find $\underset{x}{\arg \min} ||A x - b||$, where $A$ is the non-square matrix
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 & C & 0 \\ 0 & C & D & 0 \\ D & 0 & D & E \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & F\\
  e^T & e^T & e^T & e^T
  \end{bmatrix}
  .$$
  Its solution is (in overdetermined case) $x = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$ (where $b = (\underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_{4 n}, 1)^T$), which can be calculated with Gauss-Seidel method. However, $A^T A$ is, in this case, less sparse than $A$.
- Another method (that would obtain the same result as above) is to calculate the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD) of $A$ and then calculate.
- If the original $A$ (without the bottom row) is not full-rank, there is a simpler way to find the solution.

  1. Calculate the basis of null space of original $A$ (for example, by [inverse iteration method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration)).
  2. For every vector $v_k$ of that basis, divide it by the sum of its elements. If there is only one basis vector (e.g. if the entire problem is known to have a unique solution), after the division it is the solution. Otherwise:
  3. The convex hull (the set of $\sum_k \alpha_k w_k$ for non-negative $\alpha_k$ such that $\sum_k \alpha_k = 1$) of the divided vectors $w_i$ is the set of solutions.

*Implementation note for the last method*: In Matlab, the first step of the last method can be done by using `null` function. However, it involves calculating the SVD of original $A$ and doesn't work for sparse matrices, so using `eigs` to find eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ may be faster, especially since $A$ is sparse. Instead of providing $A$ for `eigs`, one can use a handle to a function that calculates $A^{-1} y$ for given $y$, for example, a Gauss-Seidel solver.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If the least squares solution is used, then the solution will be approximate or exact?

Comment: That depends on the method used in calculation of $(A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$. E.g. Gauss-Seidel method and other iterative methods inherently gives an approximate solution. If an exact method is used, then the solution is exact (up to round-off  errors, of course).

Comment: OK, got it. One more thing: Right hand side of the equation you've provided is independent from $x$ s. So how to proceed the iteration?

Comment: In the equation I wrote, $b = (0, \ldots, 0, 1)^T$ (with $4 n$ zeros), according to the original linear system and the additional equation.

Comment: Thanks again. I have a question about Matlab. I coded the algorithm as you describe above. In this problem vector $x$ represents probabilities. Thus all entities of this vector are supposed to be between 0 and 1. However, when I run the code, for large $A$ matrix (10202 $\times$ 10201), solution contains some negative values (all values are less than 1). How can I prevent this? Is there a way to force all elements to be non-negative?

Comment: Matlab functions [lsqnonneg](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonneg.html) and [nnls](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38003-nnls-non-negative-least-squares) can be used to force non-negativity. The second one is claimed to be faster on large matrices.

Comment: OK. What about using "Constrained linear least squares" in Optimization toolbox. Isn't it easier?

Comment: Since the above problem can be restated as a [quadratic programming one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares#Quadratic_programming_version), it would probably be either the same (if Matlab can detect that the problem can be reduced to quadratic programming) or more complex (if it cannot, so, for example, it cannot guess the Jacobian, Hessian and so on).

Comment: Thank you. I made significant progress with your advises. I used block Gauss-Seidel, linear least squares (ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam10-06.pdf) and Quadratic Optimization, respectively. In all cases, as coefficient matrix $A$ is large (10202 × 10201), I got the memory error. Is this normal for such big matrix or it is possible to solve it with some algebraic tricks?

Comment: Did you specify that $A$ and $b$ are sparse when inputting it into Matlab?

Comment: I did not. But as you mentioned above; $A^T A$ is not sparse at all. My code is here, if you'd like to see. Thanks. http://www.filedropper.com/anotheralgorithm

Comment: True, but $\underbrace{\arg \min}_x ||A x - b||$ can be calculated without calculating $A^T A$, so it might help some of those methods. What is the rank of original $A$ (without the bottom row of $e^T$)?

Comment: Without the bottom it is a square matrix with full rank.

Comment: Are you sure? If I understand your code correctly, $A$ with the bottom row of $e^T$ is denoted as M in the code, and its part without the bottom row has rank one less than its number of columns. If that is true for "full-sized" $A$, there is a faster way, I think.

Comment: OK. You mean there are # column - 1 linearly independent vectors in $A$. Then what is the faster way?

Comment: @AliPala I added the faster way to the answer.